# Pixelated Text in Game Maker

Tags: game-maker

[image]

Is there a way to make the text look smoother and less pixelated? It bothers me.

Comment: How are you drawing that text? What texture are you using? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you used a small size of the view then you can set a different resolution for GUI and draw text from `Draw GUI` event. Create a font with needed size and just draw it.

For example, if your window is 1024*768 (but small view - for example, 320*240)

```
display_set_gui_size(1024, 768);
```